# Eclipse android layout matrix structure

Tags: java, android, layout

I would like know how to create a layout with a matrix structure.
for example: the first row has 5 buttons, the second raw has 5 buttons, and so on.

I tried to do it without any real luck.
my programming platform is Eclipse,Java,android

Comment: TableLayout with TableRows would be a good way to go

Comment: can i do manually, by coding in XML. like relativelayout and etc.

Comment: Try  GridView. It's easy and would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). : This layout that arranges its children into rows and columns.

Below is a very basic TableLayout that creates 3 buttons in 1st row and 3 buttons in 2nd row.

You can extend this to have 5 buttons in each row by adding 2 more TableRow Object into TableLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



     <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent">
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 1 Button 1"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 1 Button 2"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 1 Button 3"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>


                        </TableRow>


     <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent">
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 Button 1"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 Button 2"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 Button 3"
                                android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>


                        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Note that, TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their rows, columns, or cells.

In case if you want to add few more rows Dynamically using java code, below is the example:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourtablelayout);
/* Create a new row to be added. */
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("add your button text here ");
b.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
/* Add Button to row. */
tr.addView(b);
/* Add row to TableLayout. */
//tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sf_gradient_03);
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Sure!! You may have to customize your layout to add cosmetic effects as per your requirements in above layout!!